# how to recognize batch file is executed or not in java?

Tags: java, batch-file, execution

I am trying to execute my batch file in java with the following code

```
String Extraction="cmd.exe /c start C:\\task\\Extracting.bat "; 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Extraction);

System.out.println("Extracted...");
```

Here, I want to execute the print statement after execution of the batch file.
But if run the above code, first it opens the command prompt and runs the batch file, and it suddenly execute the print statement before batch file runs. help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more thing that is worth a try is the following. It waits for execution

```
String Extraction="cmd.exe /c start C:\\task\\Extracting.bat "; 
//Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Extraction);

final Process p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "start /WAIT C:\\task\\Extracting.bat").redirectErrorStream(true).start();
p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Job done!!");
```

Comment: @pandian   you can then accept the answer in the post :)

Answer (score 0):

To run that command from a Java application using my new code, we'd first build and then exec the command like this:

```
// build my command as a list of strings
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("ls");
command.add("-l");
command.add("/var/tmp");

// execute my command
SystemCommandExecutor commandExecutor = new SystemCommandExecutor(command);
int result = commandExecutor.executeCommand();

// get the output from the command
StringBuilder stdout = commandExecutor.getStandardOutputFromCommand();
StringBuilder stderr = commandExecutor.getStandardErrorFromCommand();

// print the output from the command
System.out.println("STDOUT");
System.out.println(stdout);
System.out.println("STDERR");
System.out.println(stderr);
```

### Resource Link:

1. [Java exec - execute system processes with Java ProcessBuilder and
   Process (part 1)](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1)
2. [Java exec - execute system processes with Java ProcessBuilder and
   Process (part 2)](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-2)

### [Retrieving Details About Batch Jobs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/batch-1965499.html)

When a batch job is submitted, the batch runtime creates an instance of JobExecution to track it. **JobExecution has methods to obtain various details such as the job start time, job completion time, job exit status, and so on.** To obtain the JobExecution for an execution ID, you can use the JobOperator.getJobExecution(executionId) method.

```
package javax.batch.runtime;
public interface JobExecution {
    long getExecutionId();
    java.lang.String getJobName();
    javax.batch.runtime.BatchStatus getBatchStatus();
    java.util.Date getStartTime();
    java.util.Date getEndTime();
    java.lang.String getExitStatus();
    java.util.Date getCreateTime();
    java.util.Date getLastUpdatedTime();
    java.util.Properties getJobParameters();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Role of java here is to invoke cmd then it is upto OS to execute the instructions written in batch file:

You can check below code: Process handle will be returned by exec method.
By using waitFor() it waits for subprocess to finish and then returns exit code.
It will only return 1 when there is problem in path, otherwise 0 for success.

```
public class TestMe2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Process p=null;
    String Extraction="cmd.exe /c start C:\\hello.bat "; 
    try {
        p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Extraction);
        System.out.println(p.waitFor());
    } catch (Exception er) {
        er.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
    }       
}
```

}